# How to moq Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I've been trying and searching for awhile now but i can't find any way to decently mock this. I have found a way to mock the logging in quite easily with the fakehttpcontext. However this method: Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString() still won't work when you mock it like that. I'm currently using Moq as my mocking framework but can't find any documentation.

this is what i mean like with normal mocking you do this:

```
var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("Richard");
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(principal);
var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);

var service = new PersonController(mockContext.Object);
service.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
```

but those last 2 lines how does that work with your example? where in the controllercontext do I put it?

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be impossible to *mock* the method [`Membership.GetUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339.aspx) because that is a `static` method which takes no arguments.

Consider taking the `Membership.GetUser()` out of the class, and inject a `MembershipUser user` instance in your class instead. Then from the "real" code you use `Membership.GetUser()` for `user`.

From the unit test code (with Moq), you say:

```
var userMock = new Mock<MembershipUser>();
userMock.Setup(u => u.ProviderUserKey.ToString()).Returns("TheStringYouDesire");

// "inject"  userMock.Object  into what you want to test
```

Comment: I'm sorry but in which context do I put it? I can't exactly find where to put this mocking.. I mean which context of the controller :p

Comment: @Marijn Not sure I know what you are asking. You should take the code `Membership.GetUser()` out of the class, and use `user` instead. That `user` could be a private `readonly` field which is set in the non-static constructor(s). Then when you construct the class in actual (non-test) code, give `Membership.GetUser()` as `user`. From the unit test code, give `userMock.Object` instead. Maybe you are aksing something else? You can expand your original question to provide more details, then maybe someone can answer you (by editing my answer, or by providing an additional answer).

Comment: I get that but how do I get the mocked object in the class in which I need it? I'll put some code to explain in my qeustion but it's wrong code I know..